# Docker serivce remote_host failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c sudo'

Tags: docker, jenkins, centos

Got stuck with docker configuration for a remote user. When running a build command getting an error chmod: cannot access '/home/remote_user/.ssh'....'Service remote_host failed to build: The command /bin/sh -c chown remote_user:remote_user'

Further when i go to /home directory I don't see the folder created either but the step to create the folder passed successfully

The structure of the folder looks like this for main Dockerfile:

/home/useradmin/jenkins

the Dockerfile for remote_user is

/home/useradmin/jenkins/centos7

this is the main Docker file

```
version: '3'
services:
  jenkins:
    container_name: jenkins
    image: jenkins/jenkins
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - $PWD/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
    networks:
      - net
  remote_host:
    container_name: remote-host
    image: remote-host  # image that we're going to build 
    build:
      context: centos7  # where the Dockerfile is located
    networks:
      - net            # same network to allow communication between jenkins service and remote_host
networks:
    net:
```

remote_host Dockerfile

```
FROM centos

RUN yum -y install openssh-server

# Add this to fix error: passwd command not found
RUN yum -y install passwd

RUN useradd remote_user && \
  echo "1234" | passwd remote_user --stdin && \
  mkdir /home/remote_user/.ssh && \
  chmod 700 /home/remote_user/.ssh

# Modified Dockerfile for Section 4:27
COPY remote-key.pub /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys

RUN chown remote_user:remote_user -R /home/remote_user/.ssh/ && \
    chmod 600 /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys
    
    
# RUN /usr/sbin/sshd-keygen -- this has error when building, instead, use below
RUN sshd-keygen

# instruct which command the container should run/start
CMD /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

Comment: first I don't think you need a password for the user. You are going to use an ssh key anyway. You say you don't see the folders in the /home directory. which /home directory? if the image fails to build, then there is nothing to see - since there is no image. Also a full copy of the build log would help a lot more than a truncated error message. Can you post that?

Comment: That Dockerfile looks unusual to me, mostly in that there's not an application actually running in the container (and also that there are a couple of major security issues).  How are you planning to use it?  I'd consider it a little unusual to install an ssh daemon in a container and you shouldn't normally need to ssh into a container (running just a single process).